# How can I get and use the id of an object from post_params before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models.
User - has many comments
ISBN (of a book) - has many comments
Comment - belongs to User, belongs to Book

In my comment form, I have;
Comment,
user (will be hidden)
ISBN

When I submit the form, I want to check the db for the presence of 'isbn'
if yes, add comment, else if the isbn doesn't exist yet, create it and add the comment.

At the moment I can find the existence using:

```
def create
  if Isbn.exists?(isbn_number: comment_params[:isbn_id])
    create comment
  else 
    create isbn
    create comment
    save
  end
end
```

This saves the isbn number as the isbn_id which is not what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your `params` inspect and form html if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably solve this by finding or creating the association to the Isbn model in a callback block upon save. It could be done like this.

Note that I am using `:isbn_number` in the params instead of `:isbn_id`.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :isbn

  attr_accessor :isbn_number

  before_save do
    if @isbn_number.present?
      self.isbn = Isbn.where(isbn_number: @isbn_number).first_or_create!
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks man, I ended up getting it working with what I had.. I used the brute force method and few hours later lucked upon a combination that works.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. On a side note, you should be careful when you call multiple methods that save to the db in one controller action. The example in your question has the risk of successfully creating the Isbn record, but then failing to save the Comment. The result of that would be that the web client is told that the create failed, but the ISBN record is still saved in the DB and not rolled back.
It might not be a big issue in your case, but you should still be aware of it.